# Why routing doesn't work?

Tags: routes, angular

I'm trying to do wizard by new routing in angular2

my app.ts

```
import {Component,ViewEncapsulation} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {WizardCmp} from './wizard';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   template: `
     <p>header</p>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
  })
    @RouteConfig([
     { path: '/...', component:WizardCmp, as: 'Home',useAsDefault:true},
       ])
      export class App {}
```

i have only one route here with three dots notation.

wizard.ts

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router,RouteConfig,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';
import {FirstFormCmp} from './form1';
import {SecondFormCmp} from './form2';
import {ThirdFormCmp} from './form3';
 @Component({
     selector: 'wizard'
         })
 @View({

   template: `
  <h1>wizard</h1>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
         `,
  directives: [...ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
    })
  @RouteConfig([
  {path: 'first', name: 'FirstForm', component: FirstFormCmp, useAsDefault:   true},
  {path: 'second', name: 'SecondForm', component: SecondFormCmp},
  {path: 'third', name: 'ThirdForm', component: ThirdFormCmp},


 export class WizardCmp {}
```

but it doesn't show anything. And no error in console. 
  This is [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SApChDHf2wJEsdRHdjaU?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is working with small modifications http://plnkr.co/edit/bppL6TZDbRBD3mVIjw3f?p=preview...

With plunker you have to use [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/HashLocationStrategy-class.html). Maybe because app is running in `<iframe>`, don't know exactly why. But this isn't Angular2 or Router issue, but limitation of the plunker.

I just added `HashLocationStrategy` to the bootstrap:

```
bootstrap(App, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue : '/'}),
  provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})
])
```

links to the template:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Wizard', 'FirstForm']">first</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/Wizard', 'SecondForm']">second</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/Wizard', 'ThirdForm']">third</a>
```

the rest of your code was unchanged and it works...

Comment: Thank you. You saved a lot of time for me